# Type and convert text to html txt-file from a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a folder which contains a txt.file called Message. The message-file is used to update my webpage with news on the frontpage, and it is written i HTML.

I am currently working on a solution where I can type directly on my webpage in the settings-menu, into a txtBox with multilines.

- I want to be able to press a save-button which saves the text to my Message.txt-file as HTML code. How do I do this? I'm sure there are many similiar projects but I cant find anything useful.
- Also, I want to be able to preview my text on the webpage (just like Stackoverflow when I type my question.) Is there an easy way to do this?

I have googled but cant find anything useful. Can someone please guide me in the right direction? :)

The webpage is created in Angular.

Comment: For question 1 it depends where you want to store it. For question 2 you can take the value of a textarea and put in in the innerHTML of another element, do this on the keydown listener of the textarea.

Comment: Step 1: Pick a server side programming language. Step 2: Learn how to use it.

Comment: @A1rPun I want to store it in folder on the server side, where the project is stored.
The message is only supposed to be updated by the first line support, and they dont know html. That is why I want to be able to do it directly on the site and save it the folder as html code.

Comment: @ErikSellberg I understand your requirements but you are asking a very broad question. I recommend finding a way to fulfill your requirements and if you happen to have a *specific* programming question we can help you :)

Comment: @A1rPun Yes I'm aware of it. But i don't know how to specify it :(
I guess the biggest problem is turning my text into HTML.